# Is $\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2+3y^2+12z^2=0\}$ a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is $\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 :x^2+3y^2+12z^2 = 0\}$ a vector space?

My inclination is that the only real solution to $x^2+3y^2+12z^2=0$ is $(0,0,0)$, which is the trivial subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. However my true/false assignment is telling me that this is incorrect, that this set is in fact NOT a vector space. Why?

Comment: Do you mean $(x,y,x)$ or $(x,y,z)$ ?

Comment: As a sum of squared real summands it equals zero iff every summand is zero, and this happens iff $\;x=y=z=0\;$. I think the answer is yes, it is a subspace.

Comment: The only real solution is indeed $(0,0,0)$ and this is a linear space

Comment: Professors and other people who create problem sets can make mistakes too.  After all, they are only human.

Comment: You have indeed answered the question (as it was stated) correctly.  I would suspect that one of those $+$s was meant to be a $-$, which would change the answer.